# React state not updating props (using next.js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Trying to update the state of a react-date-range object (next.js) in a component with `useState / setState`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I keep getting an error that `dateRange.startDate is undefined`.

```
import {useState, React} from 'react'
import { DefinedRange } from 'react-date-range'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export const DataCard = ({...props}) => {
    let [dateRange, setDateRange]  = useState([{
        startDate: props.dateRange.startDate,
        endDate: props.dateRange.endDate,
        key: 'selection'
      }])

    const updateDateRange = (dateRange) => {
        props.dateRange = {startDate: dateRange.startDate, endDate: dateRange.endDate}
        setDateRange([props.dateRange.startDate, props.dateRange.endDate])
    }

    return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <button>
                <DefinedRange onChange={item=> {updateDateRange([item.selection])}} ranges={dateRange}/>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
)}

DataCard.propTypes = {
    header: PropTypes.string,
    dateRangeComponent: PropTypes.element,
    dateRange: PropTypes.object
}

DataCard.defaultProps = {
    header: "Graph Name",
    dateRange: {startDate: new Date(), endDate: new Date()}
}
```

Comment: Following the code from the react-date-range docs: https://hypeserver.github.io/react-date-range/

`import { useState } from 'react';

const [state, setState] = useState([
  {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: null,
    key: 'selection'
  }
]);

<DefinedRange
  onChange={item => setState([item.selection])}
  ranges={state}
/>;`

Comment: Could you show how you call `updateDateRange`?

Comment: Oops, I switched it out for a minute while debugging. Forgot to switch back. Thanks for the reminder

Comment: Are you intentionally changing the shape of your data?

Comment: No. Where am I changing the shape of my data?

Comment: @DonCarleone When you set the date range in `updateDateRange`. You start off with an array containing an object in `useState`. In `updateDateRange` you change it to an array with two raw values. E.g., from `useState([{ foo: 42, bar: 69 }])` to `setDateRange([42, 69])`.

Answer (score 1):

Your dispatch code is a bit problematic.

```
    const updateDateRange = (dateRange) => {
        console.log(dataRange)
        props.dateRange = {startDate: dateRange.startDate, endDate: dateRange.endDate}
        setDateRange([props.dateRange.startDate, props.dateRange.endDate])
    }
```

I suspect two things therefore i suggest to add a `console.log`.

##### Possibility 1

Maybe your input isn't an array, instead it's a `e` from event handler. So first need to confirm that by printing it onto screen.

##### Possibility 2

When you change something, you'd like to take changes from your input, not `prop`. So you need to think of why you are using props in the dispatch. Props are coming from parent, not children. Use local variable instead.

##### Bonus

Normally we don't render stuff inside a `<button>` element. It might be irrelevant to your problem, but might complicate your other parts of work. Use `<div>` instead.

Comment: Did I render something inside an element ?

Comment: That was a typo for `button` corrected :) , the best way is to print the input of that function and see what you get, and then drop the usage for `prop`, instead use a local variable, that's it.

Comment: BTW, prop can't be changed directly. It's something from parent, so one way to change it is through the approach you did, `onChange`. But i think you don't mean to use prop in this case at all :)

Comment: I didn't use all of the code as some of the markup is used by my company and is probably not something they want on SO, so I removed it. But the button is really part of a dropdown. It looks nice and works well as a way to change the daterange

Comment: what's a better way to update the dateRange?

Comment: if your input is correct from the function i want you to debug, then simply do `setDateRange(dataRange)`,  that's all. You have Parent, Self and Child here. But don't worry about the Parent in your problem, stick with Self and Child communication via `onChange`

Answer (score 0):

Your initial status is an array of 1 object but when you `setDateRange`, you provide an array of two objects

Your init data:

```
[{
    startDate: props.dateRange.startDate,
    endDate: props.dateRange.endDate,
    key: 'selection'
  }] // an array of a object

setDateRange([props.dateRange.startDate, props.dateRange.endDate]) // setDateRange([a, b]), array of two objects
```

It should be:

```
setDateRange((prevState) => ({ startDate: props.startDate, endDate: props.endDate, key: prevState.key  }));
```